# Hosting sitemaps in S3 and submitting them to Google Web Master Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

In robots.txt:

```
# robotstxt.org
User-agent: *
sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/sitemaps/sitemap.xml
sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/sitemaps/videositemap.xml
sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/sitemaps/imagesitemap.xml
sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/sitemaps/newssitemap.xml
```

Is it "enough"? GWT does not complain, but I can't submit sitemaps manually to GWT because it enforces my domain for sitemaps (it allows me do add/test sitemaps with URL starting from `https://www.example.com/`). Do I need to submit sitemaps to GWT if they are referenced in `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't submit sitemaps manually to GWT because it enforces my domain for sitemaps

Put up forwarding from your domain to the sitemaps, like a ProxyPass in Apache. That way, you can add it to GWT and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not enough.

The [Sitemap specification](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location) says the **location of a sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included** in that sitemap.

> A Sitemap file located at `domain/catalog/sitemap.xml` can include any URLs starting with `domain/catalog/` but can not include URLs starting with `domain/images/`.

My experience with Google Search Console is you need to submit the sitemaps to it manually rather than relying on the robots.txt reference, to get the most benefit (eg, resubmitting for a reindex).